# Does Excel does not recognize SQL Server Variable syntax?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a query that builds a table in excel. My job is to parameterize it with date variables. My boss wants to be able to change the year of a query that is built-in .xls without having to copy/paste the query in SQL Server to ctrl + F and replace years and dates, etc.

So, I parameterized this with the declaration and initialization of the date params on the top, however, when I leave them as set Year1 = '', I thought Excel would recognize the empty variable and interface a dialog box for the user to enter instead it errors out until I directly type 2017 on the query itself.

My question, is there a way to enter that data on the .xls spreadsheet before the query is refreshed as a user input pop up or dialog box?

```
declare @Year1 varchar(8)
set @Year1 = '2018'

select * from table A
```

Comment: Can you put some white space in your question? It's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you need to create a stored procedure with your query and then set some cells in excel to enter the parameters (like dates) for example. Excel will send the values in those cells to the stored procedure in the SQL Server.

Please follow the steps in this tutorial:

[Getting Data from SQL Server in Excel using parameters](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3436/passing-dynamic-query-values-from-excel-to-sql-server/)

Comment: Thank you Ignacio, this helps unfortunately it is not a Store Proc (we don't have the luxury here) for the minimal amount of data we have to create one just for this (really a convenience factor) but this does give me a new path to start doing more research. Thank you so very much!